# AWS Node JS Code Deploy SDK: Difference between registerApplicationRevision and createDeployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-code-deploy

I am writing a small utility for deploying on AWS using AWS code deploy SDK for node.js. Going through the documentation, I see the following methods:

registerApplicationRevision:

```
var params = {
  applicationName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  revision: { /* required */
    gitHubLocation: {
      commitId: 'STRING_VALUE',
      repository: 'STRING_VALUE'
    },
    revisionType: 'S3 | GitHub',
    s3Location: {
      bucket: 'STRING_VALUE',
      bundleType: 'tar | tgz | zip',
      eTag: 'STRING_VALUE',
      key: 'STRING_VALUE',
      version: 'STRING_VALUE'
    }
  },
  description: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
codedeploy.registerApplicationRevision(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

and createDeployment:

```
var params = {
  applicationName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  deploymentConfigName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  deploymentGroupName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  description: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ignoreApplicationStopFailures: true || false,
  revision: {
    gitHubLocation: {
      commitId: 'STRING_VALUE',
      repository: 'STRING_VALUE'
    },
    revisionType: 'S3 | GitHub',
    s3Location: {
      bucket: 'STRING_VALUE',
      bundleType: 'tar | tgz | zip',
      eTag: 'STRING_VALUE',
      key: 'STRING_VALUE',
      version: 'STRING_VALUE'
    }
  }
};
codedeploy.createDeployment(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

From the above code, it seems like I can create a deployment without registering a revision explicitly using the register revision method as it takes all the arguments that are required for a revision. Or do I still need to create a revision before I create revision? What is the purpose of the registerApplicationRevision method? Is there a specific method to trigger the build or will it trigger by itself as soon as I create a new deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to register a revision before creating a deployment. That will happen implicitly when you create a deployment. The only purpose in registering a revision is to add a record of it to the list of revisions before you do a deployment. The registered revision will appear in the console so you can compare what you are going to deploy to what you think you are deploying. If you aren't going to have that as part of your release process, you can skip the register step.

Note: the push CLI command stops at registration and tells you what revision it registered. So if you are using the push command the registration can be used to verify that it worked correctly.